# Convert KML file to SHP file in java

Tags: java, kml, shapefile

I have a KML file which contains multiple polygons and want to convert it to a shp file using java.

Comment: I am trying to use the ShapefileWriter of geotools...but am not able to figure out..as am new to this

Answer (score 0):

[GDAL](http://gdal.org/) is a C++ library for working with all sorts of geographic data types. It has Java bindings.

You can use Java bindings for the GDAL library. I am not a Java expert, so you will need to do research, but this should be a good place to get started: http://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/wiki/GdalOgrInJava